# Is there *any* solution to packaging a python app that uses cppyy?

Tags: python, pyinstaller, packaging, cppyy

I'm no novice when creating cross-platform runtimes of my python desktop apps. I create various tools for my undergraduates using mostly pyinstaller, cxfreeze, sometimes fbs, and sometimes briefcase. Anyone who does this one a regular basis knows that there are lots of quirks and adjustments needed to target Linux, windows, and macos when using arbitrary collections of python modules, but I've managed to figure everything out until now.

I have a python GUI app that uses a c++ library that is huge and ever-changing, so I can't just re-write it in python. I've successfully written python code that uses the c++ library using the amazing (and possibly magical) library called cppyy that allows you to run c++ code from python without hardly any effort. Everything runs great on Linux, mac, and windows, but I cannot get it packaged into runtimes and I've tried all the systems above. All of them have no problem producing the runtimes (i.e., no errors), but they fail when you run them. Essentially they all give some sort of error about not being able to find cppyy-backend (e.g., pyinstaller and fbs which uses pyinstaller gives this message when you run the binary):

```
/home/nogard/Desktop/cppyytest/target/MyApp/cppyy_backend/loader.py:113: UserWarning: No precompiled header available ([Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/nogard/Desktop/cppyytest/target/MyApp/cppyy_backend'); this may impact performance.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "/home/nogard/Desktop/cppyytest/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 628, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "cppyy/__init__.py", line 74, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "/home/nogard/Desktop/cppyytest/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 628, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "cppyy/_cpython_cppyy.py", line 20, in <module>
  File "cppyy_backend/loader.py", line 74, in load_cpp_backend
RuntimeError: could not load cppyy_backend library
[11195] Failed to execute script main
```

I'm really stumped. Usually, you install cppyy with pip, which installs cppyy-backend and other packages. I've even used the cppyy docs methods to compile each dependency as well as cppyy, but the result is the same.

I'll use any build system that works...has anyone had success? I know I could use docker, but I tried this before and many of my students freaked out at docker asking them to change their bios settings to support virtualization So I'd like to use a normal packaging system that produces some sort of runnable binary.

If you know how to get pyinstaller, cxfreeze, fbs, or briefcase to work with cppyy (e.g, if you know how to deal with the error above), please let me know. However, if you've gotten a cppyy app packaged with some other system, let me know and I'll use that one.

If you're looking for some code to run, I've been testing out packaging methods using this minimal code:

```
import cppyy

print('hello world from python\n')

cppyy.cppexec('''
#include <string>
using namespace std;
string mystring("hello world from c++");
std::cout << mystring << std::endl;
''')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT: figured out the pyinstaller hooks; this should all be fully automatic once released**

With the caveat that I have no experience whatsoever with packaging run-times, so I may be missing something obvious, but I've just tried `pyinstaller`, and the following appears to work.

First, saving your script above as `example.py`, then create a spec file:

```
$ pyi-makespec example.py
```

Then, add the headers and libraries from `cppyy_backend` as `datas` (skipping the python files, which are added by default). The simplest seems to be to pick up all directories from the backend, so change the generated `example.spec` by adding at the top:

```
def backend_files():
    import cppyy_backend, glob, os

    all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(
        os.path.dirname(cppyy_backend.__file__), '*'))

    def datafile(path):
        return path, os.path.join('cppyy_backend', os.path.basename(path))

    return [datafile(filename) for filename in all_files if os.path.isdir(filename)]
```

and replace the empty `datas` in the `Analysis` object with:

```
             datas=backend_files(),
```

If you also need the API headers from `CPyCppyy`, then these can be found e.g. like so:

```
def api_files():
    import cppyy, os

    paths = str(cppyy.gbl.gInterpreter.GetIncludePath()).split('-I')
    for p in paths:
        if not p: continue
       
        apipath = os.path.join(p.strip()[1:-1], 'CPyCppyy')
        if os.path.exists(apipath):
            return [(apipath, os.path.join('include', 'CPyCppyy'))]

    return []
```

and added to the Analysis object:

```
             datas=backend_files()+api_files(),
```

Note however, that `Python.h` then also needs to exist on the system where the package will be deployed. If need be, `Python.h` can be found through module `sysconfig` and its path provided through `cppyy.add_include_path` in the `bootstrap.py` file discussed below.

Next, consider the precompiled header (file `cppyy_backend/etc/allDict.cxx.pch`): this contains the C++ standard headers in LLVM intermediate representation. If addded, it pre-empts the need for a system compiler where the package is deployed. However, if there is a system compiler, then ideally, the PCH should be recreated on first use after deployment.

As is, however, the `loader.py` script in `cppyy_backend` uses `sys.executable` which is broken by the freezing (meaning, it's the top-level script, not `python`, leading to an infinite recursion). And even when the PCH is available, its timestamp is compared to the timestamp of the `include` directory, and rebuild if older. Since both the PCH and the include directory get new timestamps based on copy order, not build order, this is unreliable and may lead to spurious rebuilding. Therefore, either disable the PCH, or disable the time stamp checking.

To do so, choose one of these two options and write it in a file called `bootstrap.py`, by uncommenting the desired behavior:

```
### option 1: disable the PCH altogether

# import os
# os.environ['CLING_STANDARD_PCH'] = 'none'

### option 2: force the loader to declare the PCH up-to-date

# import cppyy_backend.loader
#
# def _is_uptodate(*args):
#    return True
#
# cppyy_backend.loader._is_uptodate = _is_uptodate
```

then add the bootstrap as a hook to the spec file in the `Analysis` object:

```
             runtime_hooks=['bootstrap.py'],
```

As discussed above, the `bootstrap.py` is also a good place to add more include paths as necessary, e.g. for `Python.h`.

Finally, run as usual:

```
$ pyinstaller example.spec
```

Comment: libcppyy.so is getting generated, but not libcppyy_backend.so

Comment: Those two libraries live in different packages and are build independently. Also, libcppyy.so is an actual extension library. That may be another difference perhaps: `cppyy-cling` and `CPyCppyy` packages both contain python code `cppyy-backend` does not. (Meaning, if a "freeze" installer checks e.g. `sys.modules` it will find the former two, but not the latter to package.)

Comment: Actually, I just tried pyinstaller, and _all_ of `cppyy_backend` is completely ignored. Adding it to the `data` section of the spec file improves things, but leads to an infinite recursion at startup. Disabling that with `CLING_STANDARD_PCH=none` makes it work. Let me figure that one out and then I'll update the answer.

Comment: are you suggesting something like `datas=[('/home/tseymour/Desktop/cppyytest/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cppyy_backend','cppyy_backend')]` ? If so, I definitely got some sort of recursive attempt to re-build the pre-compiled headers, but setting the env var CLING_STANDARD_PCH to none with `set CLING_STANDARD_PCH=none` didn't seem to have an effect. I'll await your next update (thanks by the way, this is already closer to a solution than I was before)

Comment: Ok, I think I caught up to you. The datas command above PLUS running it like this worked: `CLING_STANDARD_PCH=none ./dist/app/app`. Although this worked, it warned: `UserWarning: CPyCppyy API not found (tried: /home/nogard/Desktop/cppyytest/dist/app/include); set CPPYY_API_PATH envar to the 'CPyCppyy' API directory to fix` which I'm guessing means I need to add this folder to datas as well? I don't see such a folder, so I'm guessing not.

Comment: Fully updated the answer. And yes, that one, too. But those headers live in the normal 'include' path for installed packages. Will update the script above later to also take into account CPyCppyy, but from pyinstaller's documentation, it appears all this hooking can be done in the packages themselves (in their respective setup.cfg files). That would be a better long-term solution.

Comment: Thanks Wim! Everything works well in pyinstaller build apps with simple use cases (cppyy.exe(), cppy.import(), and even from sharedlibs via cppyy.load_library()). With my larger project, I eventually get this error: `input_line_49:2:19: error: no type named 'TStreamerInfo' in namespace 'CppyyLegacy'`. There's no other info, so it's hard to pin down. It's strange because CpyyyLegacy::TStreamerInfo is defined in TStreamerInfo.h which is correctly located at `/home/tseymour/Dropbox/Documents/EPICSTUFF/EPICpy/dist/EPICpy/cppyy_backend/include`) because of how `datas` in now defined. Any Ideas?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223255/discussion-between-tseymour-and-wim-lavrijsen).